# python loadtxt to read delimited file

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, split, csv

I am just switching from Matlab to Python, and would like to learn how to read this file in Python using `loadtxt` from `numpy` package. (I use `textscan` in `Matlab` to read it)

```
"07220S006","14/01/12 01:59:50",10,"0"

"07220S006","14/01/12 02:00:00",10,"0"

"07220S006","14/01/12 02:00:10",10,"0"
```

I am able to use the `split` function in Python regular expression package to read this file in, however, given my data containing about a few hundred thousands of lines like these, the `split` function applied on each single line will result in a significant analysis time. So I think `loadtxt` will do a better job in this case. I have found a number of solutions to read similar file, but this file is much more complicated than those examples and I got no idea how to read it.

Any help and recommendation is appreciated

Comment: genfromtxt is more robust than loadtxt in numpy

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation. I will spend more time on inspecting this function as my first attempt on this did not return my desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it easy with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and then if you need [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) array you could access to `values`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
"07220S006","14/01/12 01:59:50",10,"0"
"07220S006","14/01/12 02:00:00",10,"0"
"07220S006","14/01/12 02:00:10",10,"0"
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)

print(df)
           0                  1   2  3
0  07220S006  14/01/12 01:59:50  10  0
1  07220S006  14/01/12 02:00:00  10  0
2  07220S006  14/01/12 02:00:10  10  0


print(df.values)
array([['07220S006', '14/01/12 01:59:50', 10, 0],
       ['07220S006', '14/01/12 02:00:00', 10, 0],
       ['07220S006', '14/01/12 02:00:10', 10, 0]], dtype=object)
```

**EDIT**

IUUC you want to split date column to date and time (or to year, month and etc.)/ You could first convert that column to `datetime` object with [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then access to fields with `datetime` with [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html) and write it to new columns:

```
date_col = pd.to_datetime(df[1])
date_col.dt.year
print(date_col.dt.year) 
0    2012
1    2012
2    2012
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Or you could convert it string if you want any with [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), e.g.:

```
print(date_col.dt.strftime("%Y/%m %H:%M"))
0    2012/01 01:59
1    2012/01 02:00
2    2012/01 02:00
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

You could create very easy as:

```
df['year'] = date_col.dt.year

print(df)
           0                  1   2  3  year
0  07220S006  14/01/12 01:59:50  10  0  2012
1  07220S006  14/01/12 02:00:00  10  0  2012
2  07220S006  14/01/12 02:00:10  10  0  2012
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is almost exactly what I am looking for. However, when I follow your instruction, the second column is               '14/01/12 01:59:50 \n '14/01/12 02:00:00'  \n  14/01/12 02:00:10' which is a numpy ndarray type and I can't apply the loadtxt or genfromtxt on this type of data. Is there any way we can split that column and assign the values into day, month, year, hour, minute and second vectors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Treating any value in quotes as strings, and using numpy.genfromtxt instead (better at dealing with missing values):

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import String IO

example_data = '"07220S006","14/01/12 01:59:50",10,"0"\n"07220S006","14/01/12 02:00:00",10,"0"\n"07220S006","14/01/12 02:00:10",10,"0"'
# approximation of your input data

data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(example_data), delimiter=',', dtype='S16,S16,i4,S3')
# dtypes: Sx - x char string, i4 - 32 bit integer
# more here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

print data
[('"07220S006"', '"14/01/12 01:59:50"', 10, '"0"')
 ('"07220S006"', '"14/01/12 02:00:00"', 10, '"0"')
 ('"07220S006"', '"14/01/12 02:00:10"', 10, '"0"')]
```

Cant think of a simple way of removing the quote marks using numpy, I think as in the post above using pandas would probably be a better solution or python CSVReader

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's great to know about genfromtxt to load the txt file.